# Fermi's golden rule, Hamiltonian

Tags: fermis-golden-rule, nuclear-physics

I have 1 question about the Fermi's golden rule. The question is:

In the introduction of this theory, for explaining the $\beta$ decay, we suppose that the Hamiltonian is of the form: $H=H_0+H_I$ where $H_I$ is a small perturbation.

What do we mean with "perturbation"?

For example,

I know that for the selections rule of Hydrogen atom we assume that the E.M. is a perturbation.

In this case what's the perturbation?

Comment: Hi Salmone: 1. Please only ask 1 question per post. 2. Tip: Watch the right margin for duplicates.

Comment: Ok thank you,  done

Comment: Are you asking about perturbation in general or just in relation to Fermi's golden rule?

Comment: Just in relation to Fermi's golden rule